# Cursor jumps out of text field on a custom text field ! how to fix this? [Material-UI/TextField]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Guys I was using the Material-UI text-field and made some custom theme options by by making it as a custom component .

Like Below :-

```
const CustomTextField = ({props}) =>{
return (
  <TexField
   label={props.label}
   name={props.label}
   value={props.row[props.label]}
   onChange={(e)=>props.handleChangeFunction(e)}
   />
 )
}
```

In My Component I inject like below :-

```
const App = () =>{
    const [value,setValue] = useState('');
//Some methods here
   const handleChange = () =>{
   //Logic here.......
   }

 return(
   <>
    <CustomTextField {...{label:'name',row:emp,handleChangeFun:handleChange}}/> //Custom Comps...
   </>
 ) 
}
```

So What happens on each input my component renders and the cursor jumps out off the text field so for the next value to input I have to click the text field again.

But when I use the normal text field , directly in the component it works fine , I understand it is  because of the **onChange Event** and using text field in a **custom component** .

On each value change the parent compoenent re-renders .

So what will be the solution can anyone give me a solution ?

Comment: Issue Solved Guys , Don't write the custom component inside the parent component !.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your way of passing props. This should work:

```js
const CustomTextField = (props) => {
  return (
    <TextField
      label={props.label}
      name={props.label}
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.onChange}
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <CustomTextField label="name" value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Optionally you can create your component like this, without grouping props:

```js
const CustomTextField = ({label, value, onChange}) => {
  return <TextField label={label} name={label} value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
};
```

Comment: Actually what you shared second was similar to my component but anyway passing props i did mistake when i'm typing here , sorry for that . Is there any solution to solve the issue . ?

Comment: I destructured the props in starting .

Comment: I tried the code from my answer and there is no problem with jumping off cursor. But in your case maybe it is something with array called emp or logic with handleChange method.. can you share what is inside, because maybe there is the reason of problem ?

Comment: yeah wait a minute

Comment: Hey i have added the images in my question again just have a look !.

Comment: I write simplified version of this and for me it's still working as expected. It's hard to diagnose problem because there are still thinks that I don't know how works - don't know emp structure or where is the isEdit variable from inside your component?

Comment: isEdit is from my parent component but that is working fine ! ok can u share the simplified version ? Ok  the emp is object of employee details and it is mapped from an array of objects from a response.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-architecture-h00jj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: hey bro got it , u have written a onChange event inside the custom component also but i wrote only one onChange in my parent component no other in custom component maybe that causes issue i think , let me update after checking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229970/discussion-between-ram-aravind-and-tomasz-kisiel).

Comment: hey bro issue solved , its because I have written the custom component inside the parent component so that's why for every update in parent component the child inside the parent also re-renders . So cursor jumps out of the field or losses its focus.

Comment: Hey all, I also had the same issue. Thanks to @Kishieel answer it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

the best thing to do is remove your custom component to a different file & import it to the Component that you need.